# Nextjs10 not working in IE11 fine with all my arrow functions

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I have a Nextjs10 webapp. This works fine in Chrome, Safari, Mozilla, but in IE11 the app doesnt work fine. All my arrow functions dont work. How can I get my application to work fine in IE 11?

Describe the bug
In my IE11 browser this section doesn't do anything (in Chrome its open, in IE11 do nothing, its an arrow function):

[image]

Github repository
https://github.com/anialamo/nootric-next10

System information
OS: Windows 10
Browser (if applies) IE11
Version of Next.js: 10.0.3

Comment: Why use IE11 when all supported versions of Windows have Edge? IE11 remains *only* for those sites that were never upgraded to work with new standards. Its standard support is never going to be upgraded.

Comment: If you really need to target IE11 you'll have to use polyfills to provide the missing features

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos thanks! I executed this command npm install react-app-polyfill & added the following imports in my _app.js & index.js pages:            import 'react-app-polyfill/ie9';
import 'react-app-polyfill/ie11';                                                                                          But this doesn't work!

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos please! I found all my arrow functions don't work. If I replace   one by one my arrow functions then it works. Some idea to avoid this replacing?